# Cómo llamar una función programada en PHP (MVC) con Ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mvc, pdo

Me explico, tengo un proyecto realizado sólo con redirecciones, y ahora casi al final he querido implementarle Ajax para modernizar el sistema. De momento funciona así, comienza con el ControladorVehiculos que captura en la variable "$vehiculos" lo obtenido de la función consultar que se encuentra en "modelos/vehiculo.php":

```
//Acá estamos en controladores/controlador_vehiculos.php
include_once("modelos/vehiculo.php");
include_once("modelos/login.php");
include_once("conexion.php");
BD::crearInstancia();

class ControladorVehiculos
{
    public function inicio()
    {
        $vehiculos=Vehiculo::consultar();
        include_once("vistas/vehiculos/inicio.php");
    }
//Siguen más funciones abajo pero sólo necesito trabajar con esta.
//...
}
```

La función consultar dentro del modelo, la tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
//Acá estamos modelos/vehiculo.php
<?php
class vehiculo
{
    public $patente;
    public $marca;
    public $modelo;
    public $anio;
    public $fecharegistro;

    public function __construct($patente,$marca,$modelo,$anio,$fecharegistro)
    {
        $this->patente=$patente;
        $this->marca=$marca;
        $this->modelo=$modelo;
        $this->anio=$anio;
        $this->fecharegistro=$fecharegistro;
    }

    public static function consultar()
    {
        $listaVehiculos=[];
        $conexionBD=BD::crearInstancia();
        $sql= $conexionBD->query('SELECT * FROM vehiculos ORDER BY fecha_registro DESC');

        foreach($sql->fetchAll() as $vehiculo)
        {
            $listaVehiculos[] = new Vehiculo($vehiculo['patente'],$vehiculo['marca'],$vehiculo['modelo'],
            $vehiculo['anio_vehiculo'],$vehiculo['fecha_registro']);
        }
        return $listaVehiculos;
    }
    //...
}
```

Para mostrarlo en pantalla en la vista inicio.php lo hago de esta manera:

```
<!-- Y acá estamos en vistas/vehiculos/inicio.php -->
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($vehiculos as $vehiculo) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $vehiculo->patente; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $vehiculo->marca; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $vehiculo->modelo; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $vehiculo->anio; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php $vehiculo->fecharegistro; echo $newDate = date('d-m-Y H:i',strtotime($vehiculo->fecharegistro)); ?> </td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
                <a href="?controlador=vehiculos&accion=editar&patente=<?php echo $vehiculo->patente; ?>" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a>
                <a href="?controlador=vehiculos&accion=borrar&patente=<?php echo $vehiculo->patente; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</a>
            </div>
            
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Entonces lo que yo necesito es ejecutar la función consultar() desde un archivo .js en donde tengo una función que es para insertar un nuevo registro, sin tener que recargar la página para poder actualizar la tabla mostrada en el 3er script.

Espero puedan orientarme, cosa que agradecería mucho porque aún no logro entender del todo cómo funciona Ajax.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. ¿Dónde se reescribe la fila, en el cliente (HTML) o en la base de datos (PHP-Servidor) o en ambas partes?

Comment: La fila se reescribe en el cliente, pero no es ese el punto, el punto es que necesito ejecutar la función consultar( ) del modelo vehiculo.php desde un archivo .js

Comment: Por favor pulsa en [edit] para aclarar tu problema. Hablas de que la fila se reescribe. Si tal es el problema, indica dónde se reescribe. Si ese no es el problema, entonces indica cuál es el problema y dónde. Para comunicar entre cliente y servidor tú puedes usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript. ¿Tu problema es usando Ajax? ¿Qué problema en concreto tienes? ¿Qué has depurado y con qué resultados? Mientras más clara sea la exposición del problema, mejor podremos ayudarte. Nosotros no estamos frente a tu pantalla ni en tu mente para saber lo que ocurre realmente.

Comment: Me parece un poco agresiva tu respuesta, si pretendes ayudar al menos date el tiempo de leer el problema, o si tu intención es provocar quizás estás en el sitio equivocado. Dicho esto, el problema está clarito, que es querer llamar la función "consultar( )" que tengo dentro de la clase "vehiculo" cuya ruta es "modelos/vehiculos.php"

Comment: Para solucionar tu problema debes plantearte como lo harias sin ajax, es decir, solo con PHP y con peticiones POST o GET, y cuando lo tengas claro entonces es cuando debes usar ajax para realizar la petición. No hay ningun misterio ni ajax va a saber entrar en un script PHP a buscar una función de una clase de otra forma que entrarias normalmente sin el.  Y no creo que @A.Cedano haya sido agresivo, para nada, simplemente intenta ayudar (y es de los que más) planteándote preguntas para que pienses lo que haces, aunque quizás no se hayan centrado en tu problema específico en sí.